# Сортировка массива с обьектами по ключе JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular2, typescript

Здравствуйте, как отсортировать массив по значению обьекта, если это значение - слово? Вот пример массива

```html
[{
  name: 'Nastya',
  position: 'one'
}, 
{
  name: 'Tanya',
  position: 'two'
}]
```

Как отсортировать по свойству position? Есть ли варианты не изменять этот массив для сортировки? Приложение на angular , возможно там есть встроенные методы?

// вопрос решен, оказалось все очень просто:

```js
var a = [{
      name: 'Nastya',
      position: 'two'
    }, 
    {
      name: 'Tanya',
      position: 'one'
    }]

function comparePosition(objA, objB) {
  if (objA.position === 'one' || objB.position === 'one') {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

a.sort(comparePosition);

console.log(a)
```

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться вот этими [фильтрами](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

Comment: функция sort меняет исходный массив, а ты хотел _Есть ли варианты не изменять этот массив для сортировки?_

Comment: Я думал нужно добавлять в каждый обьект свойства с числами, что бы дополнить массив, и уже по них сравнивать, это имелось ввиду "изменять массив"